# Map Markers are not showing on emulator but working on real device

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-emulator

Mainly what happened App is not working on a real device but in my case, it is not working on emulator.I test app on my friend's real device (API 23). It is working fine showing all Map Markers, and other data as well.
.But on an emulator (API 23, 25, 26), it is not showing Map Markers.

**Here is my code:**

```
 protected class CreateProductListTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Product>> {

    private String serverUrl;

    public CreateProductListTask(String url) {
        super();
        this.serverUrl = url;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mDialog = new ProgressDialog(Frnt_mapActivity.this);
        mDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mDialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Product> doInBackground(Void... params) {

        HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER;

        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
        socketFactory.setHostnameVerifier((X509HostnameVerifier) hostnameVerifier);
        registry.register(new Scheme("http", socketFactory, 443));
        SingleClientConnManager mgr = new SingleClientConnManager(client.getParams(), registry);
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(mgr, client.getParams());

        // Set verifier
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);


        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("my url");

        URLConnection urlConn = null;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(this.serverUrl);
            urlConn = url.openConnection();
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));

            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(line);
            }

            JSONObject response = new JSONObject(stringBuffer.toString());

            List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
            HashMap<String, Bitmap> iconsMap = new HashMap<>();
            try {
                JSONArray productsJSON = response.getJSONArray("all_products");
                for (int ixProduct = 0; ixProduct < productsJSON.length(); ixProduct++) {
                    JSONObject productJSON = productsJSON.getJSONObject(ixProduct);
                    String mapIconStr = productJSON.getString("map_icon");
                    URI uri = new URI(mapIconStr);
                    String[] segments = uri.getPath().split("/");
                    String iconName = segments[segments.length - 1];

                    // percetn-encode URL
                    String mapIconPath = mapIconStr.substring(0, mapIconStr.indexOf(iconName));
                    String iconUrlString = mapIconPath + URLEncoder.encode(iconName, "UTF-8");

                    // replace "http:" with "https:"
                    iconUrlString = iconUrlString.replace("http:", "https:");

                    Log.d("Icon Load ", "doInBackground: "+ iconUrlString);
                    Bitmap bmp;
                    if (!iconsMap.containsKey(iconUrlString)) {
                        bmp = getBitmapFromURL(iconUrlString);
                        // populate map with unique icons
                        iconsMap.put(iconUrlString, bmp);
                    } else {
                        bmp = iconsMap.get(iconUrlString);
                    }

                    if (bmp != null) {
                        try {
                            Product product = new Product();
                            product.id = productJSON.getString("ID");
                            product.name = productJSON.getString("post_title");
                            product.lat = productJSON.getDouble("latitude");
                            product.lon = productJSON.getDouble("longitude");
                            id = product.id;
                            System.out.println("my Id stored" + id);
                            bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, (int) (bmp.getWidth() * 2.5), (int) (bmp.getHeight() * 2.5), true);
                            product.icon = bmp;
                            products.add(product);
                        } catch (Exception ignore) {
                        }

                    }

                }

            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                Log.e("App", "Failure", ex);
            }

            return products;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("App", "yourDataTask", ex);
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (bufferedReader != null) {
                try {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Product> products) {
        if (products != null) {
            for (final Product product : products) {

                Marker marker = googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(product.lat, product.lon))
                        .title(product.name)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(product.icon)));
                markerIds.put(marker, product.id);
            }
            if (mDialog != null && mDialog.isShowing()) {
                mDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
}

public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, bmOptions);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

> I don't have an android device. That's the way I have to test it on the emulator.

Comment: Are the Emulator images of the Google API's type? There are SDK images with and without Google API's. Check the version you are using

Comment: Yes, I am using Google API's type

Comment: Target Google Play is showing emulator offline. that's a way I am using Google API's.